# console.timeLog() not working in jest tests

Tags: node.js, jestjs

When I start a simple jest test:

```
describe('console test', () => {
  it('console.logTime test', () => {
    // nocommit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58961221/console-timelog-not-working-in-nodejs-12
    console.log(process.version);

    console.time('process');
    for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {}
    console.timeLog('process', 42);
    for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {}
    console.timeEnd('process');
  });
});
```

I can see a warning that `timeLog` does not recognize the `process` label:

```
  console.log src/lib/rxjs/rxjs-util.spec.ts:67
    v12.12.0

  console.time src/lib/rxjs/rxjs-util.spec.ts:73
    process: 2ms

(node:17748) Warning: No such label 'process' for console.timeLog()
```

The example is almost the same as in the docs for [timeLog()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/console.html#console_console_timelog_label_data).

Notes:

- it works in nodejs (outside of jest tests)
- jest version is `24.9.0`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Run that code outside a `jest` test, does it work? It probably will

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande right, it works, outside of the jest test - but I do need it in the tests of course...

Comment: It's not a Node.js issue, probably something inside `jest` is messing with the console. Can you show exactly where are you running that code inside `jest`? If I have time tonight, I'll mess arround with `jest` to see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande not sure what you mean by _"Can you show exactly where are you running that code inside jest?"_ - I've updated the question with some more jest info.

Comment: Wanted to know, if it was directly inside a `jest` `it/test`, like your updated answer, or not.

Answer (score 1):

As of jest v26.2.0 `console.timeLog()` is supported.